# AEM 6.1: can't fetch component properties from page nodes

Tags: aem, sightly, htl

I'm new on AEM and I have an issue:

I'm working on a page named 'ancillary'

[image: Page named ancilarry]

I did not create this page, I modified it where it was necessary.
In jcr:content I have page properties.

As you can see from the 1st screenshot:

pas
as
pos
new

are component properties, these should populate my page (ancillary), I'm only working on 'new'. The others are not used anymore since their components are now obsolete.

This is my component which we'll call 'newComponent':

[image: New component]

It should be able to fetch 'new' properties (1st screenshot), since in new's sling:resourceType I set `path/to/newcomponent`.

When I use `${properties.mynewproperty}` in newcomponent.html, it won't print the property. I can only reach pageProperties like `jcr:title`.

My component 'newcomponent' was created as a copy of another component, which it used to lay on the page ancillary and I swapped them. I also created a copy of the node with the oldcomponent's properties. I can see the component on the page on localhost, but I can't render the text properties.

I'm very sorry I explained this very badly, I hope someone understands and manages to help me.

Comment: It is really hard to understand your problem. I understood: You have a page that contains a component with `sling:resourceType= path/to/newcomponent`. Now you have created a new component (definition) with the same `sling:resourceType` as the old component and want to render the already created components in your content with this new component? But your new component is not able to render the properties? If so: are the property names identical?

Comment: At last I managed to make it work. By starting fresh new. Many thanks to everyone

Answer (score 1):

You can't access your 'ancillary/jcr:content/pas' sub-nodes properties for instance. Only properties stored under your 'jcr:content' can be accesed with "${properties.myProperty}. IF you need to retrieve those sub-node properties, you'll have to use a JAVA or JS model to access it.